# How do I echo category name and it's contents?

Tags: php, sql

Trying to create a store, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the information from my database in the right fashion.

**This is the php grabbing the information of the store, that has been clicked on:**

```
require_once "core/init.php";
include "includes/head.php";
$na = $_SESSION['name'];
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT aisle FROM aisle WHERE brand ='$na' ";
$pquery = $db->query($sql);
$pql = "SELECT * FROM aisle WHERE brand ='$na'";
$squery = $db->query($pql);
```

**The Loop I tried:**

```
<?php while($prod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($squery)): ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $prod['aisle']?>" class="container">
            <h3><?php echo $prod['aisle']?></h3>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <button>
                    <img src="fd.png" style="width: 95%" />
                    <h4><?php echo $prod['product']?></h4>
                    <h5>$<?php echo $prod['price']?></h5>

            </button>
            </form>

        </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
```

**The database**

```
║ id ║ brand   ║  aisle  ║ product ║ price
╠════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════
║  1 ║ brand1  ║  snacks ║ Bitz    ║ 3
║  2 ║ brand2  ║  drinks ║ Water   ║ 1.20
║  3 ║ brand3  ║  snack  ║ Rugi    ║ 3.05
║  4 ║ brand4  ║  sides  ║ Fries   ║ 3.95
```

Comment: what's not working?

Comment: It is creating an aisle every time a product is created. Need it to create a product, inside the aisle

Comment: i see... you'll have to use a variable to check if the previous aisle is the same as the current aisle, if the same then don't echo the aisle just echo the product and price... make sure your sql result is order by aisle

Comment: Is that the only way and easiest way to do it? because i'm just learning this and building along the way

Answer (score 0):

something like this but make sure you order by aisle

```
            <form action="" method="post">
<?php 
    $current_aisle = 'None'   #start with NONE
    while($prod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($squery)): 
        if $current_aisle != $prod['aisle'] { ?>   <!-- check if same aisle, if not then build header -->
          <div id="<?php echo $prod['aisle']?>" class="container">
            <h3><?php echo $prod['aisle']?></h3>
         <?php $current_aisle = $prod['aisle'];  }  ?>  <!-- reassign current aisle so the next iteration won't create the header -->   


                <button>
                    <img src="fd.png" style="width: 95%" />
                    <h4><?php echo $prod['product']?></h4>
                    <h5>$<?php echo $prod['price']?></h5>

            </button>


        </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something fancy with the SQL, to get an easier result to work with.

For example, you could use the following query:

```
SELECT aisle, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(product,',',price)) as product
FROM stock
GROUP BY aisle
ORDER BY aisle, product ASC
```

To get a result like:
[image: JSFiddle result]

<sub>[Here's the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57f368/6)</sub>

Comment: with that result how can you display it to the POST button?

Comment: are you saying with the products from snacks you are going to put 2 buttons there?

Comment: okay.. since you stuffed the products into 1 column how are you are going break the buttons?

Comment: good.. so why can't you create a sample code to make it helpful

Comment: don't get me wrong.. i know how you want it to work but you are not helping him by not giving a sample...